Can {targets} set the --max-connections parameter for new R sessions from parallel pipelines?
In R >=4.4.0, there is a new --max-connections option for enabling more than 128 (the default) connections in an R session.  (See see https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/parallelly/html/availableConnections.html.) The --max-connections option is not yet exposed in RStudio, but it is available at the command line. I would like to run a {targets} pipeline with more than 128 connections from the command line.
To test, I created a MWE {targets} project at https://github.com/MatthewHeun/ConnectionsTest.
The target list in the _targets.R file is simply
list(
  tar_target(
    name = conns, 
    # See https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/parallelly/html/availableConnections.html
    command = parallelly::availableConnections()
  )
)

Now I did:
# Run with the following in the RStudio console:
parallelly::availableConnections()
# The answer is 128.
targets::tar_destroy() # If you have a previous result.
targets::tar_make()
targets::tar_read(conns)
# At the RStudio console, the answer is 128.

# Try from the command line in the RStudio Terminal.
# Start a new R process with 512 connections.
R --max-connections=512
# Now type
parallelly::availableConnections()
# The answer is 512, as expected.
targets::tar_destroy()
targets::tar_make()
targets::tar_read(conns)
# The answer is 128, not 512.
# That's because {targets} starts a new process 
# in which it runs the pipeline.
# Apparently, the new process inherits the default
# number of connections (128) instead of the 
# number of connections from the parent process (512).

# Run the pipeline in the current process.
targets::tar_destroy()
targets::tar_make(callr_function = NULL)
targets::tar_read(conns)
# Now, I get 512, as expected.
# But the above executes the pipeline in a single thread.
# What about parallel processing, my use case?

# Try to run in parallel mode by uncommenting the line 
# controller = crew::crew_controller_local(workers = 2, seconds_idle = 60)
# in _targets.R.
# targets will now create 2 "runners" and execute the pipeline 
# on one of the runners.
targets::tar_destroy()
targets::tar_make(callr_function = NULL)
targets::tar_read(conns)
# Answer is 128.
# So it appears that the new (parallel) processes
# inherit the number of connections (128) from 
# the parent process.

Questions:

Is there a way to tell {targets} to inherit the number of connections from the parent process?
Is there a way to tell {targets} the maximum number of connections for child processes?

Thanks in advance.
P.S. Sorry, I couldn't get reprex() to work in the Terminal.

Have you tried using something like targets::tar_make(callr_arguments = list(  cmdargs = c("--slave", "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--max-connections=512")))?

Thanks @Axeman! I (and a colleague) are working on a solution that uses this suggestion. Note that I accepted a pull request at https://github.com/MatthewHeun/ConnectionsTest that breaks aspects of this post. But the pull request shows a possible solution and may be helpful to others.

Does that mean it works? If so, feel free to write it up as an answer to this question and accept it.

Close, but not quite. The answer is more complicated and involves the {crew} package. My colleague made a small package ({crewargs}) that demonstrates a working answer. See the readme for {crewargs} at https://github.com/rpruim/crewargs.
